Cannot assign requested address when using SlackWebhookOperator in Airflow
I'm encountering an issue when trying to send a message to Slack using the SlackWebhookOperator in Apache Airflow. The task fails with the following error:
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

The Airflow task logs show the following information:
[2024-09-26, 12:12:04 BST] {client.py:216} ERROR - Failed to send a request to Slack API server: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
...
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>

I've confirmed that:

The SlackWebhookOperator is configured with the correct Slack webhook URL
Other tasks (such as with SSHOperator for a different VM) in my Airflow DAG work correctly, so it doesn't seem to be an overall network issue with Airflow
My network allows outgoing HTTPS traffic, and there are no firewall rules blocking access to Slack's API. In fact attempting to send a POST request with the same credentials using the terminal and using a .py script inside the same Docker container I am running Airflow in works fine, i.e. a message gets sent to the configured Slack channel with no errors

What I've Tried:

Verified that the webhook URL is correct and works from other machines
Restarted the docker-compose which runs Airflow
Tried running a standalone Python script (both outside of Airflow, and inside the airflow-worker container) using the requests library to send a message to the same Slack webhook URL, but this is successful somehow

Environment:

Airflow version: 2.6.3
Running in a Docker container on Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.11
Slack SDK is up-to-date

